# Install Windows 10 on Linux HD

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

I installed Linux on my HD and I would like to dual boot into Windows. Is it possible to resize my Linux partition and install Windows along side it?

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/430956/how-to-resize-the-root-partition-using-gparted

Comment: I want to do the opposite, I already have a Linux partitions, I want to now install Windows

Comment: do the same, resize linux partition and with the new non-allocated space install windows ;)

Comment: resize task are dangerous, be carefull with it.

Comment: are their tools for backing up a Linux partition (besides just saving the `/home` directory)?

Comment: I can think of three considerations. (1) Windows may need more than one partition (EFI, recovery, etc) - I have re-installed Windows, so existing partitions were updated, but I don't know what happens on clean installations. (2) For convenience, you need the same type of boot for both systems: EFI or legacy BIOS - I presume you can install W10 without EFI (if that's how your Linux boots), but I've not tried it. (3) Windows installations don't usually allow for other operating systems, so you will need to install a compatible boot manager afterwards (eg GRUB from the Linux installation disc).

Comment: You can use gparted or partedmagic (which contains gparted) to resize your partitions.  Windows will want to be the bootable partition so you will have to re-install and configure grub.